# OCaml syntax error in functor

Tags: syntax-error, ocaml, functor

I'm trying to create a functor that makes a polynomial ring out of a ring.  My underlying type, Ring_elt, has the following signature:

```
module type Ring_elt = sig
  type t
  val add : t -> t -> t
  val mul : t -> t -> t
  val zer : t
  val one : t
  val neg : t -> t
end;;
```

My polynomial functor looks like:

```
module Make_Poly2(Underlying:Ring_elt) = struct
  type t = Poly of Underlying.t list
  let rec create lst = 
    match List.rev lst with
    | Underlying.zer :: tl -> create List.rev tl
    | _                    -> Poly of lst
end;;
```

(so the 'create' function should take a list, remove the leading zeros, and then return the polynomial of the result).  However, I get a syntax error and utop underlines the "zer" after "Underlying."

By comparison, the following code (for making integer polynomials) works:

```
module Make_int_poly = struct
  type t = Poly of int list
  let rec create lst = 
    match List.rev lst with
    | 0 :: tl -> create (List.rev tl)
    | _       -> Poly lst
end;;
```

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: You should edit the first code since you have a syntax error `Poly of lst` and a typing error `create List.rev tl`  (which are both corrected in your second example).

Comment: Thank you. Apologies for being fast-and-loose with the other syntax errors.

Comment: It seems that calling `match List.rev lst with ... :: tl -> ... List.rev tl` is an inefficient way to get the last element of a list (since you're rebuilding almost the entire list twice). Rather, make a function `last : 'a list -> 'a option`. For removing the leading zeros (as in the first zeros of the list), you would probably like a function `dropWhile : ('a -> bool) -> 'a list -> 'a list` not unlike [this one](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:dropWhile).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jeffrey's answer is good but instead of correcting it with an `if` construction, what you should do is the following : **use algebraic data types**

Instead of writing

```
val zer : t
val one : t
```

You could write

```
module type Ring_elt = sig
  type t = Zer | One | Num of t
  val add : t -> t -> t
  val mul : t -> t -> t
  val neg : t -> t
end

module Make_int_poly = struct
  type t = Poly of int list
  let rec create lst = 
    match List.rev lst with
     | Underlying.Zer :: tl -> create (List.rev tl)
     | _                    -> Poly lst
end
```

It's a much better way of doing it since you can easily pattern match on it and even add some constants to your type `t` without problems.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. A quick question regarding constants and algebraic data types: once I add the constants Zer and One, is there a way to force equality between, for instance, if my underlying type is the integers with the standard structure, how can I force the compiler to see `int 0' and see 'Zer'?

Comment: This particular algebraic type seems a little ambiguous, since `Num Zero` and `One` seem to be the same number expressed differently, and so on for `Num (Num Zero)` and `Num One`, etc. One should probably consider the convenience of having a pattern constructor for zero and one vs. the effective representation of one's numbers. I.e., you could also have `val is_zer : t -> bool` as part of your signature with the added benefit of abstraction.

Comment: @SimonShine Well, you could define the type `t` as private (in a signature) and then it would only be possible to create a value of type `t` with a proper function. Thus, it would be impossible to create `Num (Num Zero)`, for example. And `Num Zero` and `One` are not the same, are they ? I mean, one is 0, the other one is 1. :-D

Comment: @JohnBinder I don't know if it's possible and since I'm travelling soon I will try to find a proper answer soon if nobody does so before me ;-)

Answer (score 2):

An OCaml pattern is built from constants, data constructors, and new names bound by the pattern match. `Underlying.zer` isn't any of those things. But `0` is one of them.

Seems like you can just use an `if` to compare against `Underlying.zer`.

Comment: Yes, so `Underlying.zer` is a valid value constructor, but it's not a valid pattern constructor, unlike `0` that is both.

Comment: Jeremy Scofield and @Simon Shine, thank you both for the answer and comments; these are exactly the sort of quirks of ocaml that I'm hoping to get used to.  I'm accepting Lhooq's answer above but all of the answers are good ones.

Comment: @JohnBinder: Sure. I never thought of pattern constructors as quirky, but admit it was surprising when I initially learned that algebraic datatype definitions don't just create value constructors but also value destructors (pattern constructors), and that built-in value literals dub as both. It really must be such that only values that are known at compile-time will work as patterns to keep the cost of pattern matching at a predictable, low level. (If values generated at run-time were valid patterns, it could end up with the unpredictable cost of performing structural equality using `=`.)